# How can I share repeated code in multiple Excel files?

Tags: excel, vba, refactoring, shared-libraries, repeat

I started maintaining a huge number of **Excel tools** and I'm noticing that many of them have the same code, simply copy-pasted and then reused at the occurrence.

Since I would prefer to avoid copy-pasting the same code over and over, I was wondering: is there a way to refactor this code into a shared library?

**Edit**:
Please take into account that we don't have admin rights (so we cannot put files into `C:\Windows` folder) and there is only one person that can modify the code, while the others only execute it.

Comment: Yes, create an [Excel Add-in](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm).

Comment: Are the Excel macros used by other people?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Other people execute them, but cannot modify them.

Comment: If you mean uploading your code into a shared folder and then downloading that code inside the workbooks on demand, yes there is a way. I'm using it at my job because everytime I update my code, everyone had to download the new workbooks.

Comment: @Damian Yes, that would be a great solution. Can you post an answer on how you do that?

Comment: You don't need admin rights to install an Excel add-in, they're stored locally under `%appdata%\Microsoft\AddIns`. The single most important thing is that there's only ever one single "dev" version of the code, i.e. other users never make any changes. Last thing you want is to deal with conflicting modifications from two or more sources. If you need more than one dev, then consider having the code under source control (e.g. git).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the info. Yes, there is only one person that can modify the code. But the thing is, I need to update the code rather frequently. This solution would fit in this case?

Comment: The problem isn't modifying the code, it's ensuring your users are always running the latest version of it - i.e., deployment. I think users can load Excel add-ins from a network share without a local copy, but I'd have to test it before I can say for sure - this avoids needing to authorize programmatic access to the VBIDE API and modifying code as it's being executed (as below).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm interested in this, could you please tag me if you test this and works? So I could make AddIns instead of the way I do it now.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It would be great if your solution works. If you need some time, I can leave the question open for a few days (I'm sure that your solution may be useful to many people).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the AddIns way doesn't work for you, I found this on the internet a long ago:

You need to create 2 modules, ExportModule and ImportModule.

On the ExportModule you paste (and edit at will) this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExportModules()
    Dim bExport As Boolean
    Dim wkbSource As Excel.Workbook
    Dim szSourceWorkbook As String
    Dim szExportPath As String
    Dim szFileName As String
    Dim cmpComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent

    ''' The code modules will be exported in a folder named.
    ''' VBAProjectFiles in the Documents folder.
    ''' The code below create this folder if it not exist
    ''' or delete all files in the folder if it exist.
    If FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Export Folder not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Kill FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\*.*"
    On Error GoTo 0

    ''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Excel.
    szSourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbSource = Application.Workbooks(szSourceWorkbook)

    If wkbSource.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The VBA in this workbook is protected," & _
        "not possible to export the code"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    szExportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\"

    For Each cmpComponent In wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents

        bExport = True
        szFileName = cmpComponent.Name

        ''' Concatenate the correct filename for export.
        Select Case cmpComponent.Type
            Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
                szFileName = szFileName & ".cls"
            Case vbext_ct_MSForm
                szFileName = szFileName & ".frm"
            Case vbext_ct_StdModule
                szFileName = szFileName & ".bas"
            Case vbext_ct_Document
                ''' This is a worksheet or workbook object.
                ''' Don't try to export.
                bExport = False
        End Select
        If bExport Then
            ''' Export the component to a text file.
            cmpComponent.Export szExportPath & szFileName
        ''' remove it from the project if you want
        '''wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove cmpComponent
        End If
    Next cmpComponent 

    MsgBox "Export is ready"
End Sub
Function FolderWithVBAProjectFiles() As String
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SpecialPath As String

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    SpecialPath = "Z:\Planificacion-WFM\Planificacion Telefonica\Código"

    If Right(SpecialPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        SpecialPath = SpecialPath & "\"
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles") = False Then
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles"
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles") = True Then
        FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles"
    Else
        FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error"
    End If

End Function
Function DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms()
        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

        For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
            If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
                'Thisworkbook or worksheet module
                'We do nothing
            ElseIf Not VBComp.Name Like "*Modulos*" Then
                VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
            End If
        Next VBComp
End Function
```

Then the import module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ImportModules()
    Dim wkbTarget As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim szTargetWorkbook As String
    Dim szImportPath As String
    Dim szFileName As String
    Dim cmpComponents As VBIDE.VBComponents
'
'    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
'        MsgBox "Select another destination workbook" & _
'        "Not possible to import in this workbook "
'        Exit Sub
'    End If

    'Get the path to the folder with modules
    If FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Import Folder not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Excel.
    szTargetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbTarget = Application.Workbooks(szTargetWorkbook)

    If wkbTarget.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The VBA in this workbook is protected," & _
        "not possible to Import the code"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    ''' NOTE: Path where the code modules are located.
    szImportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\"

    Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files.Count = 0 Then
       MsgBox "There are no files to import"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    'Delete all modules/Userforms from the ActiveWorkbook
    Call DeleteVBAModulesAndUserForms

    Set cmpComponents = wkbTarget.VBProject.VBComponents

    ''' Import all the code modules in the specified path
    ''' to the ActiveWorkbook.
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files
        If objFile.Name Like "*Modulos*" Then GoTo Siguiente
        If (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "cls") Or _
            (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "frm") Or _
            (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "bas") Then
            cmpComponents.Import objFile.Path
        End If
Siguiente:
    Next objFile

    MsgBox "Módulos actualizados"
End Sub
```

I did change some code for my own use, so you should do the same. Both modules must be on the workbooks. Just add a button to import the modules, but go to visual basic to export them (that's what I do).

For the import to work, the user must have enabled the some macros options in excel:

[image: Options]

Sorry but my Excel is in Spanish, I'm sure you will find this on your excel.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works. I will use this for sharing code.